# Generating a Data Matrix ECC200 bar code image algorithm - Where on the internet would I find this exact algorithm?

Tags: barcode, datamatrix

Where would I find the exact algorithm for generating a Data Matrix ECC200 bar code image that would eventually be printed? I've seen plenty of general explanations but nothing sufficient enough to write code from. I realize of course that there are libraries for this but I'd like to reinvent this particular wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datamatrix symbology is defined by the standard ISO/IEC 16022 available at:

https://www.iso.org/standard/44230.html

If you poke around the web a bit, you may find a copy....